# For the subspace $\left\{ \left( a,b,c\right) :a-3b+c=0,b-2c=0, 2b-c=0\right\}$, find a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

- For the subspace $\left\{ \left( a,b,c\right) :a-3b+c=0,b-2c=0, 2b-c=0\right\}$, find a basis.

From the set, we get, $a=2c$, $b=c$. **My question is:How can I find a basis? Can you help, can you give a hint?**

Comment: **What have you tried?**

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't know that how I can find. But, I know that the vector should be linearly independent and spans the space.

Comment: solve the system of equations fr $a, b$ and $c.$

Comment: @Bumblebee $a=0,b=0,c=0$ right?

Comment: @Kahler: Exactly. Therefore you have the corresponding subspace.

Comment: @Bumblebee thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis for this subspace is the same as the basis for the solution system to the following matrix equation
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-3&1\\0&1&-2\\0&2&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

An additional hint: it is very easy to see that this matrix (the coefficient matrix on the left) has nonzero determinant. What does this tell us about the solution system to the above equation?

Comment: I will find $a,b,c$. Thus, $\left\{ a,b,c\right\}$ will be a basis for us, right?

Comment: Yeah, the solutions to that matrix equation are the vectors in your subspace.

Comment: Hence the solution is $(0, 0, 0)$. The solution space contain only $(0, 0, 0)$ element.